# How to get first key value in JSON?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I want to conevrt JSON data into HTML table dynamically using javascript/jquery. I have JSON like,

```
     {
        "Transaction Details":
        {
         "txnId":"TP20151515151S45",
         "txnNo":"201548484848484",
         "txnDate":"09-JAN-2021",
         "txnStatus":"success"
        }
     }
```

I am able generate HTML table using jquery for below JSON,

```
{
               "txnId":"TP20151515151S45",
               "txnNo":"201548484848484",
               "txnDate":"09-JAN-2021",
               "txnStatus":"success"
       }
using below code

var col = [];
for (var i = 0; i < txnJson.length; i++) {
   for (var key in txnJson[i]) {
       if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
       col.push(key);
       alert(key);
       console.log(key);
       }
   }
}
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
   var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
   th.innerHTML = col[i];
   tr.appendChild(th);
}
for (var i = 0; i < txnJson.length; i++) {

   tr = table.insertRow(-1);

   for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
       var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
       tabCell.innerHTML = txnJson[i][col[j]];
   }
}
$('#Div<%=i%>').append(table);
```

but I want to get "Transaction Details" as a table name and other details like txnId as key(header) and TP20151515151S45 as value(row).
I have tried by getting first key using Object.keys(obj)[0], but not able to achieve the same.
How it can be done?

Comment: Try [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). If you need more specific help, please edit your question to the code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: var col = [];
for (var i = 0; i < txnJson.length; i++) {
 for (var key in txnJson[i]) {
  if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
  col.push(key);}}}
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                  
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
 var th = document.createElement("th");   
 th.innerHTML = col[i];
 tr.appendChild(th); }
for (var i = 0; i < txnJson.length; i++) {
 tr = table.insertRow(-1);
 for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
  var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
  tabCell.innerHTML = txnJson[i][col[j]];
 }} $('#Div<%=i%>').append(table);

Comment: Using above code, I am able to generate second JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. Now I'm able achieve the same using below code,

```
var tableName;
var colspan = 0;
var colHeader = [];
var rowValue = [];
for (var key in txnJson) {
    tableName = key;
        console.log(key);
    for (var secondKey in txnJson[key]) {
        console.log(secondKey + ' : ' + txnJson[key][secondKey]);
        for (var thirdkey in txnJson[key][secondKey]) {
            colHeader.push(thirdkey);
            rowValue.push(txnJson[key][secondKey][thirdkey]);
            colspan = colspan +1;
            console.log(thirdkey + ' : ' + txnJson[key][secondKey][thirdkey]);
        }
    }
}
```

This might help someone.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to call JSON.parse() on your JSON string to create an actual Javascript object. Then you can do something like this:

```
tableData = JSON.parse(my_json)
for (prop in tableData)
{
   console.log(prop) // should output your keys, txnId, txnNo, etc
   console.log(tableData[prop]) //should output your your value for that field
}
```

You can use this loop to generate your DOM elements for the table.